# Why does Haskell allow a list of Shape, but no list of Square or Circle or Triangle

Tags: list, oop, haskell, functional-programming, polymorphism

Why does Haskell allow to do a list of Shape as in the first exemple, but not as in the second example? As far as I know, both lists would have elements that are either

```
{ name :: String, position :: Vector3D, radius :: Double }
```

or

`{ name :: String, position :: Vector3D, dimensions :: Vector3D }`.

ex 1:

```
data Shape
    = Sphere { name :: String, position :: Vector3D, radius :: Double }
    | Prism { name :: String, position :: Vector3D, dimensions :: Vector3D }
```

ex 2:

```
data Sphere = Sphere { name :: String, position :: Vector3D, radius :: Double }
data Prism = Prism { name :: String, position :: Vector3D, dimensions :: Vector3D }
```

I want to know why it is possible to do a list of Shape, but no polymorphic list of Sphere and Prism even though they have the same members than when declared through the data type "Shape".

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  Possibly with an example of what you want to do?  As you have your question right now it's rather difficult to understand what you're actually asking.

Comment: I am not trying to do anything in particular, I just want to know why it is possible to do a list of Shape, but no polymorphic list of Triangle, square...

Comment: I think the question is why with the first datatype you can write `[Sphere ..., Prism ..]`, but not with the second datatypes. If that is  the case, it is because all the elements in a list must have the same type.

Comment: @user2407038 But as far as I know, a Prism is identical no matter what way, of these two, is used to create it. What are the practical reasons why a list of either Sphere or Prism would work if declared through the data type Shape, but not if not declare through it?

Comment: @MickaelBergeronNéron Yes, `Shape` in example 1 is the same as `Sphere or Prism` in example 2. In fact, that is exactly what the `|` symbol means in data type declarations. But Haskell does not care that the two are isomorphic. *You* have declared them as separate types, *you* have made the assertion that "these two things are distinct". But we also have a datatype in Haskell used to represent "or", we call it `Either`. You can have a list of type `Either Sphere Prism`: `[Left (Sphere ...), Right (Prism ...)]`.

Comment: In the first case, `Prism "thisprism" .....` has the type `Shape` but in the second case it has the type `Prism`, so in that case you've said it's a _different_ type to a Sphere. Haskell won't overrule you.

Comment: You keep saying polymorphic list.  I'm pretty sure you mean hetrogenous list.  Haskell's list type is polymorphic but homogenous, as is the case is many statically typed languages.  Some of those langauges also have support for subtyping (usually explicit [a.k.a. nominal] and not implicit [a.k.a. structural]), but Haskell does not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because in ex1, `Sphere` and `Prism` are not types but constructors. They are both of the same type `Shape`. Therefore you can create a list of `[Shape]`. Moreover, as they are not types, `[Sphere]` doesn't even make sense, because `Sphere` is not in the type namespace. I don't know if that's what is  confusing you, but when I started learning Haskell I was mixing up constructors and OO subclasses. They are different. In that context (**ex1**) you can't have thing like :

```
radius :: Sphere -> Double
```

Because `Sphere` is not a type. `Sphere` is a function which returns `Shape`.

Now, in **ex2**, `Sphere` and `Prism` are types so you have either have

- a list of spheres `[Sphere]`
- a list of prisms `[Prim]`
- a list of one or the order as pointed by AndrewC `[Either Sphere Prism]`.

An alternative solution is to declare a `Shape` class for stuff which have a name and a position.

```
class Shape  a where
    name :: a -> String
    position :: a -> Vector3D


data Sphere = Sphere { sphereName :: String, spherePosition :: Vector3D, ... }
instance Shape Sphere where
  name s = sphereName s
  position s = spherePosition

data Prism = Prism { primsName :: String, prismPosition :: Vector3D, ... ?
instance Shape Prirm where
     name p = prismName p
     position p = prismPosition p
```

Now, you can have a list homogenous shapes, example :

```
names :: Shape s => [s] -> [String]
names ss = map name ss
```

By homogenous, I mean you can't mix prisms and spheres in the same list.

Answer (score 10):

### Different types

In your second example,

```
data Sphere = SphereTag { sphereName :: String, 
                          spherePosition :: Vector3D, 
                          sphereRadius :: Double }
data Prism = PrismTag { prismName :: String, 
                        prismPosition :: Vector3D, 
                        prismDimensions :: Vector3D }
```

you've declared that these are two different data types. You can have the types `[Sphere]` and `[Prism]` but not `[Shape]` (because you haven't defined a `Shape` type in this example).

I've renamed the fields because otherwise `name` had two types `name :: Sphere -> String` and `name :: Prism -> String`, and that's not allowed without using a typeclass.

I've renamed `SphereTag` and `PrismTag` to make clear the distinction between the type `Sphere` and the data constructor `SphereTag`

### One type

In the first example

```
data Shape
   = SphereShape { name :: String, position :: Vector3D, radius :: Double }
   | PrismShape { name :: String, position :: Vector3D, dimensions :: Vector3D }
```

there's *one* type, so you can make `[Shape]`.

### Either - tagged union

The classic way of combining two types is with Either, which tags data from the two types with `Left` or `Right`:

```
type PrismOrSphere = Either Prism Sphere

myList = [Left (SphereTag "this" ...), Right (PrismTag "that" ....), ....]
```

but you're probably better off with your custom Shape type.

### Advice for coming from OOP

Try not to re-use OOP teaching examples as functional programming examples. OOP examples are designed to teach you OO principles first and programming second, and they're designed very much for developing your OO and imperative thinking.

It's like trying to learn to fly a plane by manoeuvring round an empty car park. It's very hard to go slowly round a car park on a plane, whereas it's probably the first thing you learned when driving your car.

If you insist on learning flying by trying to replicate your driving lessons, you'll just see your plane as a *very* inconvenient kind of car that won't fit down lots of roads.

You should use a well-written set of examples designed to teach functional programming. I recommend [Learn You a Haskell for Great Good](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) which comes in both web and dead tree versions.

### Polymorphic in OOP vs FP

In Object Oriented Programming, what you usually call polymorphism is implemented using superclasses. You can have a ShapeList made up of subtypes of Shape or an EmployeeList made up of managers and cleaners, but then in traditional OOP you'd need to write *different* but similar code to implement `.sort` methods on each of those. We could call this subtype polymorphism. It's different to the sort of polymorphism you get from generics where you could write a single method to work on any type.

In Functional Programming, what you usually call polymorphism is implemented by being completely agnostic about the type of your data, so you can write a single function `reverse :: [a] -> [a]` that will work for any possible list, of Shapes or Spheres or Employees or whatever, more like generics but with no runtime type data overhead (see [Does Haskell erase types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12468722/1598537)). We could call this parametric polymorphism. It's different to the sort of polymorphism you get from typeclasses where you allow multiple types to have the same named function.

Comment: (fixed some typos (I think)) double-plus-good for different type and constructor names, for novices!

Comment: @WillNess Well, double-plus-good __with__ your edit, perhaps, and considerably less clarifying without! Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

What you are saying isn't actually correct, both the examples which you have provided are *not* list.

```
data Shape
    = Sphere { name :: String, position :: Vector3D, radius :: Double }
    | Prism { name :: String, position :: Vector3D, dimensions :: Vector3D }
```

The above example is an example of Algebric data type.

The second example that you show is an example of record data declaration for Sphere:

```
data Sphere = Sphere { name :: String, position :: Vector3D, radius :: Double }
data Prism =  Prism { name :: String, position :: Vector3D, dimensions :: Vector3D }
```

That being said, in Haskell List are homogenous types. They can only hold values of the same type. (Although you can overcome this by using Existential quantification, don't do that as it as an antipattern.)

Also from your example one, you can make that as list of type `[Shape]` which can contain both `Sphere` and `Prism`. Example:

```
λ> let a = Sphere "sph1" 2.2 3.4
λ> let b = Prism "prism" 3.4 4.8
λ> let c = [a,b]
λ> :t c
c :: [Shape]
```

In the above example, I'm assuming that `Vector3D` is of type `Double`.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you properly, it sounds like your understanding is that the data type

```
data Shape
    = Sphere { name :: String, position :: Vector3D, radius :: Double }
    | Prism { name :: String, position :: Vector3D, dimensions :: Vector3D }
```

and the data **types**

```
data Sphere = Sphere { name :: String, position :: Vector3D, radius :: Double }
data Prism = Prism { name :: String, position :: Vector3D, dimensions :: Vector3D }
```

are the same thing. They're not (but it's an understandable assumption from an OOP perspective)!

`Shape` is what is called a "Sum Type" -- a data type that can have one of many forms, in this case `Sphere` or `Prism`. You can make a "polymorphic list" of `Shape`s because, in essence, *the data type itself is polymorphic*. A `Shape` can have two different types of values associated with it.

In your second example, `Sphere` and `Prism` are two completely separate, disjoint data types. You can glue these together with `Either` as suggested in another answer, but they do not have the same type and can't be contained in the same list together -- it wouldn't make sense.

You're probably used to *subtyping* which isn't present at all in haskell -- we rely on things like sum types (like `Either` or `Shape`) to allow values to have multiple (tagged!) types of values. It's different than what you're used to. In Haskell, values and expressions have *a single type*, you can't say that a `Sphere` (in your second example) is a `Shape` because it isn't! It's a `Sphere` and nothing else. In your first example, a `Sphere` is a `Shape` by definition, so `[Shape]` is a valid type.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may be confused about how types work in Haskell. Haskell uses parametric polymorphism and class-based ad-hoc polymorphism. It does not have anything like structural subtyping. Names given to fields of a data constructor are tied up to the type declared there; they can't be reused elsewhere. Even with a GHC extension that allows such reuse, the reused names are not related to each other.

Comment: I think this answer is pretty much impenetrable to a newcomer.

Comment: @luqui, the question appears to me to suggest familiarity with systems that do things differently. My aim was to suggest that Haskell doesn't work like those.