# What is type variable in haskell/Java

Tags: java, haskell

Today we mentioned type variable. But I don't understand what it means. I can only find one explanation on wiki, [type variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_variable)

I understand the explanation in math, but still, have no idea about programming. Can anyone give an explanation?

Comment: I think you're only going to find ocaml examples for type variables, they aren't implemented in the mathematical sense in Java. And when I hear haskell, I think [monad](https://wiki.haskell.org/Monad) (but I don't really know haskell).

Comment: Where did *we* mention type variables? Anyway, are you asking about a Java generics type variable, also known as a "[type parameter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html)" (⇐ Link to "The Java™ Tutorials")?

Comment: @Andreas Well, just now for you...

Comment: @ScaryWombat Just because I think that using better scoped words (like `field` and `parameter`) where appropriate, given that `variable` is too wide in meaning, in order to prevent confusion/miscommunication, that doesn't make me a word-nazi. ;-) Bad code happens when miscommunication occurs, so as a good programmer, you should support me. :-P

Comment: @Andreas and I should realize that humour does not always work on the net.

Comment: @Andreas True, I'm asking type parameter. I thought it is the same as type variable because our professor wrote type variable/parameter on the blackboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Type variables you can define a datatype/container for things (Numbers, Text, ...) of a non-specified type. To provide an easy example, imagine, you want a Box, where you can put in anything you want.

Here is an example in Java (T is the type-variable):

```
public class Box<T> {
    private T thing;

    public void putThing(T thing) {
        this.thing = thing;
    }
}
```

Here is an example in Haskell (a is the type-variable):

```
data Box a = PutThing a
```

Another good example would be a generic tuple datatype.

---

**Example usecases**

Note, in both cases the type-variables are now specified types.

Java:

```
Box<String> box = new Box<String>();
box.putThing("42");
```

Haskell (in ghci):

```
:t (PutThing (42::Int))
(PutThing (42::Int)) :: Box Int
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's very easy. The basic observation is that we do not only have basic types like Int and Bool and Char, but types composed from other types.

The simplest example are lists. In a type safe language, all elements of a list must have the same type. That is why we write:

```
Haskell   Java               Explanation
[Int]     List<Integer>      list of integers
[Char]    List<Character>    list of characters
```

and so on. This is nice already, but not nice enough. It turns out that certain functions on lists are absolutely identical except for the element type, and that the element type is irrelevant inside the function. Here is an example:

```
lengthIntList :: [Int] -> Int    -- compute length of a list of int
lengthIntList [] = 0
lengthIntList (x:xs) = 1 + length xs

lengthCharList :: [Char] -> Int    -- compute length of a list of char
lengthCharList [] = 0
lengthCharList (x:xs) = 1 + length xs
```

Therefore, the next step is to abstract from the element type and say:

```
length :: [a] -> Int       -- length of a list, for all elemen types
length [] = 0
length (x:xs) = 1 + length xs
```

Here, the `a` is a type variable that says: For all types, this function `length`takes a list of that type and returns an `Int`.

Answer (score 2):

The example from wikipedia can be written in Java like this

```
public static <T> T identity(T a) {
    return a;
}
```

where the type of `a` is bound to the type parameter `T`. So when you call the identity function with an `Integer` you get back an `Integer`, when you call it with a `String` you get back a `String`.

A very common usage example would be a collection of values of the same type like a list of Strings:

```
List<String> as = new ArrayList<String>();
```

The type parameter in the `List` interface is bound to `String` therefore all elements of that list must be of type `String`.

Updated code snippet, thanks Elliott.

Comment: What is `t` in your example? Did you mean `return a;`?

Answer (score 1):

A type variable is a way to have polymorphism by writing a single function/method that works on multiple different types of values. Here is an example in Haskell:

```
id :: forall a. a -> a
id x = x
```

The `a` in the type signature is a type variable, and as the `forall` implies, this function works "for all" different types. For example, you can use `id` as if it had the type `Int -> Int` or as if it had the type `Char -> Char`.

```
id (5 :: Int) = 5 :: Int
id 'a' = 'a'
```

If `id` was given a concrete type (meaning without type variables in it) such as `id :: Int -> Int`, then `id 'a'` would be a type error because `'a'`'s type (`Char`) doesn't match `Int`.

Usually, we omit the `forall` (`id :: a -> a`) because it can easily be inferred from the use of type variables, but it is helpful for understanding what is really going on.

I don't know as much Java as Haskell, but Generics seems to be a way to use a type variable, so `ArrayList<A>` means an array list that works for any non-primitive type `A`.

Comment: Java Generic types don't work for primitive types, and they are a compile time type safety system (they are mostly *erased* at compile time). So they aren't "pure" in any sense...

Comment: @ElliottFrisch What do you mean they don't work for primitive types? Can I not use `ArrayList<boolean>`? [*All* type information in Haskell is erased at runtime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468722/does-haskell-erase-types), so they are similar in that respect. How does any of this impact how "pure" anything here is? If you mean pure as in "no side effects", I don't see how that applies here at all.

Comment: No. You can not use `ArrayList<boolean>` *or* `ArrayList<int>` for that matter. You'd have to use the wrapper types.